# How to set time zone by default in php?

Tags: php

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$x ='2016-03-15';
echo date("j M [D] Y",$x);
```

But when i run this code it show wrong output : 1 Jan [Thu] 1970

and i want the output like : 15 Mar [Tue] 2015.

please help me, what's wrong in this code.

Comment: `'2016-03-15'` is not a timestamp, and you probably had a warning raised by PHP (if you've got them set to display)

Comment: enable your PHP warnings: `A non well formed numeric value encountered in [...][...] on line 3`

Comment: I was unaware there are timezones which are -46 years... Learn something new every day...

Answer (score 6):

Your question title is misleading, your time zone setup is just fine. Date display isn't.

`date` expects second (optional) parameter to be a Unix timestamp, not a date. Convert your date to unix timestamp first.

```
echo date("j M [D] Y",strtotime($x));
```

This can be seen on the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

> string date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing the *date* function: the second parameter must be a **timestamp**, not a string.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

In order to get timestamp from a date, you can use *mktime* or *strtotime* functions.

Answer (score -2):

strtotime — Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$x ='2016-03-15';
echo date("j M [D] Y",strtotime($x));
```

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)